# lcov respectively geninfo cannot read gcda files

Tags: gcov, lcov

I'm are trying to setup lcov on a local Windows computer using cygwin and the bash shell. I installed the newest version of lcov downloaded from here: [lcov at sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ltp/files/Coverage%20Analysis/LCOV-1.14/lcov-1.14.tar.gz/download).

When I call a specific gcda file, then I get an output.
The call is: `lcov -c -d FileName.gcda -o outputfile.info`

As far as I read usually lcov shall be able to iterate over all gcda files in a folder. My call for rotating over all gcda files is:

```
lcov -c -d . -o outputfile.info
```

With the above code I get the following output:

```
Capturing coverage data from .
Found gcov version 6.4.0
Scanning . for .gcda files ...
geninfo: WARNING: no .gcda files found in . - skipping!
Finished .info-file creation
```

Here a screenshot:
[image: lcov failure]
As can be seen, there is a CanAdapter.gcda and CanAdapter.gcno, but with the configuration above geninfo produces a failure.

When I try to make a call like this:

```
lcove -c -d *.gcda -o outputfile.info
```

I get the following answer:

```
lcov: Extra parameter found: 'FileName2.gcda'
Use lcov --help to get usage information
```

I read the help, and it doesn't help as much as I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

On windows machine there are two possibilities to run lcov.

1. In the cygwin folder there is a batch script calling "Cygwin.bat".
   Run this script.
   When the scripts opens type the following line:

> lcov -c -d /cygdrive/c/path where the gcda files are located -o /cygdrive/c/path where the output folder is located/lcov.info

The same is to do with genhtml to create the html file.

2. You can open the windows cmd.exe. After this you need to add the following line:

> sh -c -l "lcov -c -d /cygdrive/c/path where the gcda files are located -o /cygdrive/c/path where the output folder is located/lcov.info"

It is important to write

> sh -c -l

and the lcov command in

> " "

otherwise lcov and genhtml wont work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the lcov manpage -d is used to specify a directory to use.

So try

`-d .`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you can see, I add to my posting a screenshot for better understanding. As you can see, there ist the "-d ." parameter in my call of lcov.

Comment: I am sorry, I used lcov exactly like this and it works. On Linux I would now run strace to find out, why it doesn't find the file, but I am not sure about Windows

Answer (score 0):

I run lcov on Linux like this :

> lcov --c --directory . --output-file main.info

This works fine with my setup.Try running pwd when you open shell to see if you are currently in the same directory or not.